# Getting rid of strange eggs in houseplant soil

Tags: houseplants, diseases, pests, lily

Help! I have a peace lily which I bought three years ago for almost a nothing as it was almost dead. I nursed it back to health and was doing great, after about a year of having it in it’s nursery pot I repotted it in a bigger pot using normal potting soil for house plants although I do believe it said “compost” so not quite soil. I’m not very experienced in plants and gardening at all but I just wanted to save the plant, I even kept the instructions tag it came with! Three years since (two years since repotting) it has developed a strange green/white mould looking substance and I have no clue what it is or how to get rid of it. I need help! I’ve scoured the internet and I still am unsure. Here’s how it looks.[image] [image]

If anyone could help me I’d be very grateful!

Thanks so much in advance x

Answer (score 1):

This is, just as you thought, a mould, which lives off the organic matter in the soil.  Remove it and provide more air circulation if possible.  Stirring up the top half inch of the soil sometimes helps too

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give that a go.